# Bootstrap sidebar expand on the right side

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to expand the links in the side navbar horizontally. I have tried hard by going through the tutorials of bootstrap 4. My code is following.

```
    <li class="active dropright">
        <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="dropdown-toggle">
            <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
            Residential
        </a>
        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Rami Villa</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Alpine Metals Jafza</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

The outcome of this code is as following.

[image: Picture when I open the file]

.

**When I click the residential link it dropdowns as follows.**

[image: Dropdown upon click]

.

**However I actually want something like this.**

[image: Desired outcome]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `.dropdown-menu` on your `<ul>` instead of `.collapse`

```
    <li class="active dropright">
      <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="dropdown-toggle">
        <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
        Residential
      </a>
      <ul class="list-unstyled dropdown-menu" id="homeSubmenu">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Rami Villa</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Alpine Metals Jafza</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Home 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/chan_omega/a3mgvnk8/

Answer (score 1):

I have do some modification in your code, and has done the output as your requirement.

**HTML**

```
<aside>
  <li class="active dropright">
    <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="dropdown-toggle">
      <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
      Residential
    </a>
    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled submenu" id="homeSubmenu">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Rami Villa</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Alpine Metals Jafza</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Home 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</aside>
```

**CSS**

```
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

aside {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
}
aside .dropright {
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}
aside .dropright a {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}
aside .dropright .submenu {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  left: 100%;
  right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
aside .dropright .submenu li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
}
```

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/dudts/pen/ZEBXKbN) link
[image]

Comment: Actually, I am trying to connect it like dropright. When I click on resedential, then the popup should work

Comment: check the [codepen](https://codepen.io/dudts/pen/ZEBXKbN), you will get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite new to programming, but why don't you use the example of Bootstrap:

Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Default dropright button-->
    <div class="btn-group dropright">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Residential
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <!-- Dropdown menu links-->
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Rami Villa</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Alpine Metals Jafza</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Home 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't want to put it in buttons, a lot of extra work is needed to handle CSS with this approach.

Comment: True, but it's not too hard to remove all button stylings.